# Multiple apk files in bin directory

Tags: android, eclipse

I had a look at my project in the windows explorer and I saw that there's a bin folder containing other previous apk files.

Is this normal and is there a reason these are being retained?

Is it safe to delete these extra apk files?

I created the new project copying first a previous project then renaming it via Eclipse.

Is this the reason I am seeing these additional apk files in the project bin folder?

Thanks for helping
Angelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can delete all contents of bin ,when you run your new code, bin contents are autogenerated.

Comment: Thank you both, I will make such changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete compiled binary files in Eclipse, as they will be compiled when needed.